# Which site deals with theoretical database questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Which site deals with theoretical/conceptual database questions?

Also, which deals with conceptual and practical questions about database management systems such as about structure and working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) would probably be the best place to get answers about theoretical/conceptual database questions.

I've also seen some good conceptual database questions on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), providing the question falls within the scope of conceptual software development.

Comment: @AshRj Haha thanks, this will have been the 3rd time I've gotten 10k rep. I keep giving it away on bounties :)